# OCaml - Why is Either not a Monad

Tags: ocaml, bind, monads

I'm new to OCaml, but have worked with Rust, Haskell, etc, and was very surprised when I was trying to implement `bind` on `Either`, and it doesn't appear that any of the general implementations have `bind` implemented.

- JaneStreet's `Base` is [missing it](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Either/index.html)
- What I assume is the standard library is [missing it](https://ocaml.org/api/Either.html)

`bind` was the first function I reached for... even before `match`, and the implementation seems quite easy:

```
let bind_either (m: ('e, 'a) Either.t) (f: 'a -> ('e, 'b) Either.t): ('e, 'b) Either.t =
  match m with
  | Right r -> f r
  | Left l -> Left l
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: IMHO this is more of a philosophical discussion than a Stack Overflow (I'm having a specific problem, how do I solve it) question. I recommend asking on the OCaml Forum. Short answer: your implementation signature does not conform to monadic bind, which requires _one_ type parameter on the monadic type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because we prefer a more specific [Result.t](https://ocaml.org/api/Result.html), which has clear names for the ok state and for the exceptional state. And, in general, Either.t is not extremely popular amongst OCaml programmers as usually, a more specialized type could be used with the variant names that better communicate the domain-specific purpose of either branch. It is also worth mentioning that Either was introduced to the OCaml standard very recently, just 4.12, so it might become more popular.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/janestreet/base/issues/111#issuecomment-848038992

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @ivg, Either is relatively new to the standard library and generally one would prefer to use types that make more sense. For example, [Result](https://ocaml.org/api/Result.html) for error handling.
There is also another point of view, which also applies to Result. Monads act on types parameterised by one type.
In Haskell, this is much less obvious because it is possible to partially apply type constructors. Hence; `bind:: (a -> b) -> Either a -> Either b` allows you to go from `Either a c` to `Either b c`.

In trying to generalise the behaviour of a monad via parameterised modules (functors in the ML sense of the term), one would have to "trick" oneself into standardising, for example, the treatment of `option` (a type of arity 1) and `either` (or `result`) which are of arity 2.

There are several approaches. For example, expressing multiple interfaces to describe a monad. For example describing `Monad2` and describing `Monad` in terms of `Monad2` as is done in the Base library (https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Monad/index.html)

In [Preface](https://github.com/xvw/preface) we used a rather different (and perhaps less generic) approach. We leave it to the user to set the left parameter of Either (via a functor) (and the right parameter for Result): https://github.com/xvw/preface/blob/master/lib/preface_stdlib/either.mli

However, we do not lose the ability to change the left-hand type of the calculation because Either also has a Bifunctor module that allows us to change the type of both parameters. The conversation is broadly described in this thread: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/instance-modules-for-more-parametrized-types/5356/2